# xcode 6 unable to scroll a long uitextview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

My app has a UIscrollview with a height of 800, and subview with a height of 800 and a UItextview with a height of 1000 scrolls a few lines. If I reduce the height to 500 it scrolls more lines. This seems counterintuitive. Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can get a larger UItextview to scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UITextView` is a scroll view, so, like a regular scroll view, it will scroll if the content takes up more space than the text view.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors in my approach. I got it completely wrong ... the fact that autolayout keeps resizing the height of the textview and/or giving me Misplaced Views warnings made me think I needed to use a scrollview. How do I tell Auto-layout to stopped giving me these warnings? I've tried to get it to "Update the constraints" but that just results in it changing one of the vertical constraints.

Comment: You need to have enough constraints to unambiguously define the text view's size and position. (If you need more help than that, you should mark this answer as correct, and open a new, separate question about your auto-layout constraints.)